# sudo update stucks at connecting

Tags: server, sudo

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server, and I want to install the GUI, which causes error everytime. but before installing the GUI, I want to run the update command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But I always get this error: [image: http://www.aedes.us/i/Jx0p.png]

It stuck at the "Connecting..." and then after some seconds it says failed and such.

Note that my nameservers are set to these:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

What should I do?!

Comment: It looks like a DNS issue. Are you able to browse the internet fine? Please post the output of this: `nslookup us.archive.ubuntu.com` and `nslookup security.ubuntu.com`

Comment: both says:

;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you either have a network/connection issue or a DNS issue. First, try to ping 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS Server, as you already know)

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

If you get a response, we can tell that it is a DNS issue. If not, it is a network/connection issue.

For a DNS issue, make sure that you have set the DNS as described. Check `/etc/network/interfaces`. You should have a line in your network card stanza, like this:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Notice that the DNS servers are separated by a space, not a comma. A typical full stanza would look something like this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.50
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.4
```

After making the change, restart your networking service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

If that doesn't work, please post the contents of your `/etc/network/interfaces` config.

Comment: when I ping it, it only says: "PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data." Nothing happens from then (actually nothing). I restarted my server and tested it again, its the same. Is it a Network issue?! What should I do?

Comment: By the way I just edited my /etc/network/interfaces with your example. Still get the same error.

Comment: It should say something along the lines of `64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=55 time=37.3 ms`. Yes, this is a network issue then. Can you ping your gateway, as defined in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: It says: Destination host Unreachable

Comment: Yeah, you definitely have a networking issue. Check to make sure everything is plugged in and that you have blinking lights on your ethernet port, etc.